# C# why cant i exit this while loop?

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm tryig to make a program that can auto press space. 
but i can only enable it. after the program crashes.

so i cant turn it off. pleace help

here is my code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Auto_Abillty
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public bool startFlag = false;
    public bool stopFlag = false;
    private void Preiststop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopFlag = true;
    }
    private void Preist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        startFlag = true;
        while (startFlag)
        {
            SendKeys.Send(" ");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            if (stopFlag)
                startFlag = false;
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: probably because your UI is tied up in the while loop and so you cant click another button to turn J to true

Comment: Think of creating a thread to send space key.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is blocking the UI thread.  Look into using `Task.Delay` and `async\await`.

Comment: If it is not necessary to check only every 5 seconds, you could look into custom events too

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` with 5000 ms interval instead of your approach. Then by clicking on the button on a form you may start or stop it.

Another approach is to move your `while` loop into another thread that will make UI thread still be responsive

Answer (score 0):

You must abort the thread as well.

```
public bool x = false;
public bool j = false;
private void Preiststop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    j = true;
}
private void Preist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x = true;

    Thread newThread = new Thread(delegate ()
    {
        DoPriestWork();
    });

    newThread.Start();

    //loop to wait for the response from DoPriestWork thread
    while (x)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        if (j)
            x = false;
    }

    newThread.Abort(); 
}
public void DoPriestWork()
{
    //x = true;
    //while (x == true)
    //{
    SendKeys.Send(" ");
    //Thread.Sleep(5000);
    //    if (j == true)
    //        x = false;
    //}
}
```

Comment: the program still crashes so  it does not work but thanks for trying to help

Answer (score -1):

Your `Preist_Click` call blocks the UI: it executes in the same thread, instead of starting its own.

Try this:

```
private bool keepRunning = true;

private void Preiststop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    keepRunning = false;
}

private async void Preist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    keepRunning = true;
    await Task.Run(() => {
        while (keepRunning)
        {
            SendKeys.Send(" ");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code *still* executes it in the UI thread.  You haven't started a new thread (although starting a new thread would also be wrong; you should make the code asynchronous without using any new threads).

Comment: @Servy - you're right: I added `Task.Run`... to the answer

Comment: And now you have the second problem that I already mentioned, and also an `async` method with no `await`.

Comment: Why would you `await` something that doesn't return anything? To handle a possible exception? Yes, VS complains about no await, but that is hardly a problem.

Comment: Since you have nothing to `await`, then the method shouldn't be `async`.

Comment: Why is that? if the task is to separate the execution from UI, having async with no await is perfectly fine

Comment: i can say so much to it that it still dosent work but ty for trying to help

Comment: @Lasse - see my edits. I just compiled and ran sample above

Comment: @user270576 In your example marking the method as `async` is accomplishing literally nothing (because of all of the ways I've mentioned you're doing it wrong).  If you were actually using it to compose asynchronous operations, then it could actually be helpful.  You're not using it to do that.

Comment: @Servy - my example (after all the edits) effectively disengages `Thread.Sleep(5000);` from holding up the UI - i.e. it solves @Lasse's original problem

Comment: @user270576 No, your code *doesn't* work, as was mentioned by the OP themselves, and the fundamental approach has numerous flaws, as I've pointed out myself, even if you corrected the mistake that is causing the code to crash.  That you don't care about all of these problems, and have no interest in writing effective code, is unfortunate, but I obviously can't force you to care.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like all you need is a thread so another button can be pushed to change the condition of "j". If there is only one thread, the UI will not be updated until that thread is stopped hence the need to make another thread, like below example.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}

public bool x = false;
public bool j = false;
private void Preiststop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    j = true;
}
private void Preist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread newThread = new Thread(DoPriestWork);
    newThread.Start();
}
public void DoPriestWork()
{
    x = true;
    while (x == true)
    {
        SendKeys.Send(" ");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        if (j == true)
            x = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: program still crash